# Macro to clear all columns after last header name runs but does not clear

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear all the columns after the last header row

The macro runs but `no clearing` happens, I have played with the syntactic for awhile and am not getting it

Thanks

```
Sub ClearColumnsAfterLastHeader()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim hNames As Variant
Dim cell

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Finished")
 hNames = ws.Range("A1:R1").Value

For Each cell In hNames
If IsEmpty(cell) Then
    cell.EntireColumn.ClearContents
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your code is that `hNames` is *array of Variant* rather than `Range` and when you're looping through array `For Each cell In hNames`, variable `cell` refers to *array element* rather than to corresponding cell. So, you can't use `cell.EntireColumn.ClearContents`, because `cell` is *not* `Range`, but `Variant`.

As per my understanding of question, you want to determine last filled cell in *first* row (header row) and clear contents of all *columns* to the right of last filled header. In that case try code below:

```
Sub ClearColumnsAfterLastHeader()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastHeaderColumn As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Finished")

    With ws
        'determine last filled cell in first row
        lastHeaderColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'get of all cells to the right and down and clear contents
        .Range(.Cells(1, lastHeaderColumn + 1), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just do something like

```
Sub ClearStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range, ClearRange As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Finished")
    Set LastCell = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count)
    Set ClearRange = Range(LastCell.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1), LastCell)
    ClearRange.EntireColumn.ClearContents
End Sub
```